# Event listener on button not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

So, my menu for my game is in a separate .fla file and I have used a loader like so to load the menu into my game:

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.system.LoaderContext;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.Socket;
import caurina.transitions.Tweener;


public class Main extends MovieClip {

public static var gameLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
public static var endGameLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
public static var menuLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;

public var gameTime:int;
public var levelDuration:int;

public function Main()
{
    addChild(gameLayer);
    addChild(endGameLayer);
    addChild(menuLayer);

    var myMenu:Loader = new Loader();
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Menu.swf");
    myMenu.load(url);
    myMenu.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, menuLoaded);

    function menuLoaded(event:Event):void
    {
        menuLayer.addChild(myMenu.content);
    }

    playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
}



public function startGame(e:Event)
{
    // Code to remove the menu (menuLayer.removeChild?)
    // Code here to start timers etc
}
```

I set instance names for my buttons but when I try to do something like `menuLayer.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);`, I get messages saying `Access of undefined property playBtn`.

Now, I double checked on my Menu.fla and I definitely gave the button an instance name of `playBtn` but it's not working. Any help please? Might be something really obvious I've missed but I'm not sure what.

EDIT: Trying it another way (Converting the menu to a movieclip) but not 100% sure how to do it exactly. The code I have is:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {

var mainMenu:menuMain = new menuMain;
// Other variables

 public function Main()
   {
        addChild(gameLayer);
        addChild(endGameLayer);
        addChild(menuLayer);

        menuLayer.addChild(mainMenu);
        mainMenu.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, menuLoaded);
   }

   function menuLoaded(event:Event):void
   {
         //var mainMenu:LoaderInfo = event.currentTarget as LoaderInfo;
         //var menuInstance:MovieClip = menuLayer.getChildAt(0) as MovieClip;

         // now you can actually add the listener, because the content is actually loaded
        mainMenu.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
   }

    public function startGame(e:Event)
    {
       // Code to execute timers etc.
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is menuLayer ? Is it a symbol from the library that you instantiated via the linkage class name ? You need to post more of your code as it is. If you are getting an error on that line, it's because menuLayer doesn't have a playBtn. I'm going to trust that the error is correct.

Comment: Im guessing, but could be an issue because you are not directly adding the Loader to the display list (i know you are adding the Loaded content but maybe Loader doesnt like it that way). Try "menuLayer.addChild(myMenu);" in menuLoaded method instead of current code

Comment: Updated the code. `Access of undefined property playBtn` error is the only error I have at the minute. Using "menuLayer.addChild(myMenu);" in the menuLoaded method gives the same error.

Comment: In the code you've posted you've written `playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);` whilst in the comments you've used the correct syntax which is `menuLayer.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);`. Which one is it?

Comment: Both of them give the same error regardless. I tried both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you think that when you go `menuLayer.addChild(myMenu.content)` that menuLayer suddenly becomes an instance of `menu.swf` That is not the case. It becomes a child of menuLayer.

Try this :

```
menuLayer.addChild(myMenu.content);
var menuInstance:MovieClip = menuLayer.getChildAt(0) as MovieClip;
trace (menuInstance.playBtn);
```

This code assumes that you have nothing else added to menuLayer and in that case your menu.swf content would be the only child on the display list of menuLayer.

I am also assuming that menu.swf's contents are a MovieClip.

If my assumptions are wrong, this may not work.

I also noticed that you have your menuLoaded method inside your constructor. Not a good idea. Especially since the next line is expecting playBtn to exist and the menu hasn't even been loaded.

Try something like this :

```
public function Main()
{
    addChild(gameLayer);
    addChild(endGameLayer);
    addChild(menuLayer);

    var myMenu:Loader = new Loader();
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Menu.swf");
    myMenu.load(url);
    myMenu.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, menuLoaded);



}


function menuLoaded(event:Event):void
{
     var myMenu:LoaderInfo = event.currentTarget as LoaderInfo;
     menuLayer.addChild(myMenu.content);
     var menuInstance:MovieClip = menuLayer.getChildAt(0) as MovieClip;

     // now you can actually add the listener, because the content is actually loaded
     menuInstance.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
}


public function startGame(e:Event)
{

    // Code to remove the menu (menuLayer.removeChild?)
    // Code here to start timers etc
}
```

Comment: The Menu.swf is made up of a static text item and four buttons but the buttons are the only things I want to add event handlers to.

Comment: Are all those things on the stage of menu.swf ? Is the instance name for the button `playBtn` ? Check the properties panel to ensure that the button has the instance name `playBtn`. Keep in mind that the symbol name is NOT a instance name.

Comment: Yes, all of these objects are on the stage. I checked the properties panel and the instance name is definitely set as `playBtn`

Comment: I'm not going to play charades debugger here. This is likely an issue of you having your content setup incorrectly if the above code doesn't work. You can send the files in question to prototype.in.training@gmail.com and I can take a look at them. You have inconsistencies in the posted code and what you said in the comments, so I'd rather take that aspect out of the equation.

Comment: Ok, updated my answer, this should work if your content is as you say it is. You were also trying to add that listener before the content even existed. And your syntax assumed that playBtn existed as a class variable, which it doesn't

Comment: My upload speed is really slow, will take hours to upload. If I use `playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);` the error is `1120: Access of undefined property playBtn` and if I use `menuLayer.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);` the error is `1119: Access of possibly undefined property playBtn through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite`

Comment: I have updated my answer as I said, and it works just fine. I created the content needed on my side, based on how you described you had your menu.swf set up. This works fine for me. It's the best I can do for you. -- this last comment you give has menuLayer.playBtn, but if you read my answer, I tell you that is not going to work.  Above code works, if you at some point choose to actually use it.

Comment: I was working within your parameters. I don't think this is the ideal way to go about doing what you are trying to do. Unless there is a good reason to have the external menu.swf, you are just adding complexity that isn't needed.

Comment: I don't know any other way of doing it that will yield similar results without being too complicated to figure out / implement since I am relatively new to AS3

Comment: Why not have a menu as a movieclip in your library that has linkage set ? That's a whole lot less complicated than loading in a menu.swf, and this question shows that it's too complicated for your current understanding. Right ?

Comment: I suppose I could do that, although I'd run into a similar problem with the undefined playBtn but I guess it'd be easier to resolve and work with.

Comment: Why would you run into an undefined problem? The reason you are running into it here, is because you don't understand how the Loader works and tried to add the listener before the loading occurred.  Far simpler to just go -- `var mainMenu:MainMenu = new MainMenu;` and then be able to use that instance. Loading a .swf is just adding the complexity of loading and a handler etc. If you don't have a good reason, why ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to correctly execute it properly when storing the menu movieclip in a variable. I get the menu to show and everything but clicking the 'Play' button doesn't do anything. Not quite sure how the event handler should be tweaked as I assume that is the issue